# Xamarin.Forms BackgroundImage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

i want to implement a background image for the entire app.

I use the global style.xml `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/appbg</item>` on Android. How can I achive this on iOS?

Is somethig like this possible?

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, 
  NSDictionary options)
{
  ...
  UIWindow.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(
    UIImage.FromFile("appbg.jpg"));
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with a CustomNavigationPageRenderer.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(OIdx.XForms.Pages.CustomNavigationPage), 

typeof(OIdx.XForms.iOS.Renderers.CustomNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace OIdx.XForms.iOS.Renderers
{
    class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            var img = UIImage.FromBundle("appbg5.jpg");
            UIImageView iv = new UIImageView(img);
            iv.Layer.ZPosition = -1;
            this.View.AddSubview(iv);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I haven't been able to get it to work for me yet. The overrided ViewDidLoad() is being called, but the app doesn't change. Any ideas there? Was there anything else you had to do to get it to work?

Comment: Ok, got it. I just had to give the ContentPage elements of my XF pages a transparent background. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** In your `AppDelegate` assign the `Window.BackgroundColor` a `UIIamge` via `UIColor.FromPatternImage`:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    Window.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(new UIImage("background.png"));
    return true;
}
```

**2nd:** In each `View` that you wish to see this background, you have to set the `UIColor` to `Clear`:

```
View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

Note: Multiple image sizes should be used so each device get a resolution appropriate image.

FYI: This is a memory hog that effects the entire life span of the application, it is really bad if this is not a texture/tiled image (iOS or Android) and actually a *single* image actually spans the entire screen.

Comment: If I set the BackgroundColor this error appears `Foundation.ModelNotImplementedException: Exception of type 'Foundation.ModelNotImplementedException' was thrown.`.

Comment: @mlauth Do you have a custom `UIApplicationDelegate` that you did not override the `Window` property? Or remove the `Window` property from the template-created `AppDelegate`? Using a really old version of Xamarin.iOS with iOS4?, Using really old/outdated code from a repo?

Comment: To test this, I have just created a test project everything is up to date as far as I can tell. The same error in Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio.

Comment: @mlauth Do you have a overriden `Window` property in the `AppDelegate` that was created?

Comment: @mlauth Here is a *complete* AppDelegate.cs, this will allow the background code to work properly: https://gist.github.com/sushihangover/f2e32bf3be1706a9d9916113cc0e44aa

Comment: I'm getting the same error as @mlauth even after overriding the Window property per SushiHangover's instructions.

Comment: @Jonathan see my answer below, this should work. For Android use the style.xml.